# How to structure CHEF for multiservers environments using data from a database

Tags: chef-infra

Im pretty new in CHEF, i've just red the proper chef fundamental, and im trying to build up a specific configuration.

**EXAMPLE**

**INTRODUCTION:**

There is an enviroment composed by 10 servers (server1, server2, ecc..)
Assuming they are Application Servers and they have for example an application installed.

**INTRODUCTION 2:**

server1 has to be 1.1.1.1
server2 has to be 1.1.1.2
ecc..
server1 application.conf must have a value "AAAA" inside
server2 application.conf must have a value "BBBB" inside
ecc..

**PROBLEM:**

- workstation side
  I have a single cookbook example [hostname]
  and I have a single cookbook [application]
  both with some keyholder somewhere..
- and now...
  i have a database (postgres,mysql,sqlite,whocare)
  with a table SERVERS where :

Servername= "server1"
PrivateIP= "1.1.1.1"
PublicIP= "100.1.1.1"
Application_text= "AAAAA"
...
...

**QUESTION:**

Is there any auto way to get values from the database and using them with the cookbook?

Thanks

Comment: There's plenty of ways to accomplish that, all in end dealing with setting node attributes for a particular node by combination of cookboko attributes, roles attributes and environment attributes. We can't give you a 'Do like this' as its very opiniated and dependent on your needs. As far as I understand your question, the database is not even needed and could be a cookbook defining a server, each cookbook would be a line of your table here...

Comment: Can you:
A - remove the database from the equation completely
B - populate the database from Chef, rather than Chef from the database?

Comment: @Tensibai
yeah but my purpose is to have just only one cookbook.

Comment: @MarcoGiusti Its probably a bad idea, as you won't have control on moving parts through dev -> Q/A -> prod tunnel (i.e update needed asap on apache but app n+1 already in test and you can't skip it). The only one cookbook for an app is ok, having specific env value in environment or in wrapper cookbook per environment overriding the default value. But its still opinion based on what I understand from your question and what I know from experience and chef mailing list history.

Comment: @Tensibai
you right, i will reorganize the structure then, thanks!

Comment: @MarcoGiusti I would recomend what is the current 'consensus' on cookbooks if you're starting which is berkshelf See information about it here https://www.getchef.com/blog/chefconf-talks/the-berkshelf-way-jamie-winsor/ and here http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/ and this (a litlle older) http://www.prashantrajan.com/posts/2013/06/leveling-up-chef-best-practices/